# How to display each elements of loop to table row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, loops

how to return each element of loop. I mean i want display each name of this loop to row text. It is only return last element. How can i return all of this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellFullname = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        for last in lastnames {
            cellFullname.textLabel?.text = "\(last)"
        }
        return cellFullname
    }
```

Comment: remove for loop do like this lastname[indexpath.row]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop for displaying the elements in `UITableView`

Say you have an array of last names:

```
var lastnames = ["....
```

And you want to put each element in a UITableViewCell. Two steps:

1. Define the amount of cells you need:

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
       return lastnames.count 
   }
   ```
2. Update the `UITableView` with the names:

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cellFullname = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)


       cellFullname.textLabel?.text = lastnames[indexPath.row]

       return cellFullname
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the part where you're assigning the `textLabel.text` :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellFullname = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)


    cellFullname.textLabel?.text = lastnames[indexPath.row]

    return cellFullname
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better create an array of elements arr[].
Use this :

```
cellFullname.textLabel?.text = arr[index.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated:
Just access each element of lastnames using `indexPath.row.`

```
    let cellFullname = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    cellFullname.textLabel?.text = lastnames[indexPath.row]

    return cellFullname
}
```

If you will add for loop with in `cellForRowAt` then for each cell creation that loop will run, which not good as well.